# Can memcached clients distribute key data to multiple instances?

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

During some testing of multiple memcached instance I realized that spymemcached Java client was evenly distributing the key data across the configured instances. I know that memcached is a distributed, but is there a way to configure a client to write key data to all configured instances? I know that memory cache approaches like this are not designed to replace persistent storage (DB) but I have zero need for persistent storage and need a lightweight way to synchronize basic key/value data between two or more instances of my service.

The test Java code I prototyped worked great, and I feel the spymemcached API would integrate well, but I need to replicate the data between memcached instances. I assumed if I specified multiple MC instances that the data would be distributed to all, not across all available. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is some memcached client that allow data replication among multiple memcached servers. From what I can tell, SpyMemcached is not one of them.

I do not understand however, why you want this. Lightweight synchronization works just as well without replication. Memcached clients generally (this includes SpyMemcached) use consistent hashing to map from a key to a server, so every instance of your service will look for a key on the same server.